# While function trouble

Tags: python

For some reason, when I try to set a `while` function, it doesn't do what I want.

For example:

```
import random  

x = 0  
while x <= 10:     
    print random.randint(1, 100)     
    x += x + 1
```

This only runs four times. But if I change it to `while x <= 1000:` it runs ten times. Any idea why?

**EDIT**

I am sorry, But think this is a legitimate question. Please stop downvoting me! Next time I will do more research into the syntax for problems as simple as this. Sorry.

Comment: `x += x + 1` should be either `x+= 1` or `x = x + 1`.

Comment: @Rawing: prepare to 5 copies of your comment as answers...

Answer (score 1):

To increment `x` by 1 you should use

```
x += 1
```

or

```
x = x + 1
```

You have combined them into `x += x + 1`, which adds `x+1` to `x` each time.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `x += x + 1` is essentially adding `x + (x + 1)`. Simply remove the initial `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `x + 1` to `x`. It should be `x+=1`, that makes you finish sooner:

Start: `x = 0`

After first iteration: `x + x + 1 = 0 + 0 + 1 = 1`

After second iteration: `x + x + 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3`

After third iteration: `x + x + 1 = 3 + 3 + 1 = 7`

After fourth iteration: `x + x + 1 = 7 + 7 + 1 = 15`, which is greater that 10 and stops.

You are multiplying x by 2 and adding 1, so it's not an error just is the answer to another question.